# Can a pronoun 'one' be used together with possessive pronoun their?

Tags: pronouns

After reading this discussion: [is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their), I was wondering if I could use one and singular they together in a sentence.

A sentence for an example:

> Quite frankly, one needs to get their head screwed on right.

Is that sentence above acceptable grammatically? I also wonder whether I need the pular form of *head* i.e. **heads** after **their**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a dissonance between *one*, which has a formal feeling, and *head screwed on right*, which is very colloquial.
Apart from that, I think it's better to stick with *they*:

> They need to get their heads screwed on right.

(note plural *heads*),

or with *one*:

> One needs to have one's arguments ready.